# Icon for "show image in lightbox" button (pictogram style)

Tags: image, icons, lightbox

The context is an image properties dialog in a CMS backend. Here the backend user has the option to let the website visitor see (a full-size version of the) image in a lightbox when clicking it.

- What would be a suitable icon for such an backend option, when the restrictions are a grayscale pictogram style icon of maximum 32 x 32 pixels?

In my mockup the icon looks like this:

[image]

Update: To be more specific concerning style, my other icons are inspired by the look of these: http://www.iconsweets2.com/

Answer (score 3):

Do these help?

http://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=expand

http://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=full+screen

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: These are some good suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Vitaly - but am just starting on this site so I can't vote him up.  I think most users would appreciate the 4 arrows approach because it signify's full screen/larger representation pretty universally.

I don't know if there is a benefit to trying to find an icon to let them know it is specifically a LightBox vs.  a full/larger screen representation.

Comment: Vitaly gave multiple icons. Which do you specifically find best?

Comment: Chris, I think you're right about the Lightbox/larger screen distinction. The casual backend users probably don't know/care it's called a lightbox so to them it's just a matter of providing them the opportunity to let website visitors see the image in a larger version.

Comment: I like the 1st and 3rd icon.  http://www.iconsweets2.com/ has a set of arrow icons and the last three are actually appropriate [two actually being potentially of use for the lightbox example - even though I don't like that paradigm - as agib said - they want bigger regardless of how it gets bigger].

Answer (score 2):

#### Popout

The site you linked has one in their iconSweet2 set that looks like an image pop-out (the right one). I think **this is best representing a lightbox**:

[image: image pop-out from iconSweet2]

#### Zooming

BTW, iconSweets has a shop - [Icon shelf](http://www.iconshelf.nl/) - where they actually use a zoom icon to let people know they can view a larger version in a lightbox. This could be **an alternative**, but I guess this one works better for visitors then in the redaction backend.

[image: zoom icon from Icon shelf]

*The black and white zoom overlay shows when hovering the item.*

Their icon sets (iconSweet and iconSweet2) also have such zoom icons:

[image: zoom icon from iconSweet]
[image: zoom icons from iconSweet2]

#### Fullscreen

I don't really like the fullscreen icons, to me they mean something else. Although many users will maybe not feel any difference between fullscreen and a lightbox with grayed out background..

iconSweets2 also has one. To me, here you clearly see this means something else. However, when in another style it might work better.

[image: fullscreen icon from iconSweet2]

Comment: Concerning the rightmost icon in your Popout section, I actually already use something similar in another part of the GUI - here it represents image drop shadow.

I have my doubts concerning the magnifier glass icon since it besides zoom also very often signifies search - so there's an inherent ambiguity.

The Fullscreen icon is an okay suggestion - however, it might also refer to drag'n'drop actions.

Comment: Just saw you added the iconsuites examples.  I like their designs very much.